# How can I set system-wide grayscale with exception of some apps?

Tags: macos, display, catalina, system-settings

Does anyone know how to enable system-wide Grayscale with the exception of some user chosen Apps, which would have colors?

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done.

Greyscale in Accessibility is in effect an 'overlay' or filter for the entire screen. It is done right at the point the image is sent to be drawn by your GPU. No app is even aware it is set.

You can very easily test this by switching on greyscale & taking a screenshot.
Switch off greyscale again & look at the shot you took - it's in colour.

Comment: I appreciate this answer. However, from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316498/macos-grayscale-except-some-apps (older macOS), it seems like there are solutions... I'm just wondering if there's a Catalina compatible hack.

Comment: Sorry, that's completely outside my area of expertise. try commenting on that answer & see if the OP replies.